# How to generate C# enum as TS enum using Servicestack types generation?

Tags: typescript, servicestack

When generating TS types using Servicestack we get our enums as string literal types. Is there a setting to make SS generate them as TS enums instead?

Comment: C# Enums are already generated as TypeScript Enums, what version of ServiceStack are you using?

Comment: @mythz I'm using ServiceStack 6.9.. When I use types/typescript.d I get my types as interfaces, but my enums as string literal types. But maybe I'm supposed to use types/typescript, but then I get my types as classes and my enums as enums. Solution?

Comment: Yeah `/types/typescript` is what most people use.

Comment: @mythz Yes but why can't I get the types generated as interfaces using that endpoint?

Comment: Because it generates types, not interfaces.